# Oracle APEX, проблема с пробелами в числовом поле

Tags: oracle-apex

У меня есть таблица, где я храню ИНН (varchar) и номер банковской карты пользователя (number). Я создал страницу где я добавляю новую запись в таблицу.  На этой странице два поля  для этих колонок (number fields). Я форматирую значения этих полей с помощью JS:

- поле ИНН: '111111111' -> '111 111 111';
- поле для номера карты: '1111111111111111' ->  '1111 1111 1111 1111'.

Также я передал этим полям маски (Appearance -> Format mask):

- 999G999G999 (ИНН);
- 9999G9999G9999G9999G9999 (карта).

При добавление новой записи в ИНН сохраняется с пробелами, а номер карта без пробелов. Это все из=за типа ИНН (varchar). Я хочу хранить ИНН без пробелов. Можно ли реализовать это без JS?